How should I repair a crack on my garage slab at the overhead door line?
We recently bought a house with a garage attached to it. Like many garage concrete slabs, it is cracked, just outside of the garage door (see picture).

Since the area sees a lot of car/motorcycle traffic, we don't want to patch it with a concrete mix: we believe it will just crack again under the weight of the vehicles and the harsh canadian winter (you can prove us wrong though, I'm really open to suggestions). Therefore, we wanted to gather educated suggestions on how to patch the crack. We read about Sika self-leveling sealant, Flex Seal, epoxy (I'm however not equipped for epoxy/not very good with my hands), maybe use a foam backing rod (the crack is however not that wide), etc.
What would be your take on that one?

Welcome. Please take the [tour].

Sikaflex Crack Flex or similar will work after cleaning out the divot.

What I would suspect from this picture is that crack continues under the wall across that whole corner. I don't see that crack traveling up into the block or brick work on the wall. This was most likely caused by settling of the subsoil.  Good news is its a tight crack and isn't progressing.  I seriously doubt there's movement from vehicle traffic because it's a tight crack(not widening) and I assume there's a frost wall directly below the crack.  The surface chipping around the crack I would guess are freeze spalling.
I would want to prevent water intrusion and freeze cycles.
My repair would be chiseling out a "V" along the crack 1/2" deep.  Blowing clean with air and applying hydraulic cement, less than $10.
Hope my assumptions are correct and wish you good luck.
GBowman

I would suggest a bonding cement product.    If you need suggestions leave it in comments.

Clean area.
Wet area
Add bonding cement.
scrape with trowel.   I would error on the side of scraping under flat.    Anything sticking out will lend itself to falling out or cracking.

I do not thing you have any structure issues.   Replacing this would be ludicrous without trying many options.    I suspect that you had a hairline crack, water got in and now the ice cycles has made it worse.
The goal here is so no more ice pops out more concrete.    It seems the main issue here is the garage door has quite a bit of garage concrete in front of it.    When we pour garage slabs we want them pretty flush with the door because of this exact issue.   The garage door is acting as a damn (and house/garage is shading area) and causing ice cycle issues in concrete.   I would suspect that the crack made that are worse but that issue will probably continue along the garage door for the whole garage (maybe this area is shaded more?).
What I am getting at here is that fixing this is short-term.    You probably need to cover that section of concrete.    I would think about installing a strip of epoxy on your garage floor there maybe an inch or two into the garage or at the very least give that strip a coat of paint with drylock (yes won't last long but also cheap and easy).   I could see painting that section lasting a couple of years and concrete lasting much longer.

To do a cosmetic surface repair you'd need something flexible, as you suspect. Anything brittle will just crack along the existing lines of movement. Note that almost anything is likely to make this area more conspicuous, though, so ask yourself what you're actually trying to accomplish.
I would probably not try to fill the entire cavity, but simply clean out the crack thoroughly and seal it alone with a small bead. We don't do product recommendations here, so read some labels and see which offers you the additional qualities you require.
A proper long-term repair would involve cutting out that section of slab and re-pouring it. You would probably want to set the new joint inside the door line so it's subject to less weather.

Would you go as far as to say that the repair I'm trying to do is unnecessary, especially since the crack in the floor doesn't represent any structural issue? Should I be worried that the crack spreads and become larger with time? Thanks again.

"Necessary" is subjective. Any repair should mostly be to slow the degradation of the surface due to freeze cycles. There's no structural concern here.
